# Problems uploading pictures from camera capture with input type="file" capture="camera" using JQM -> Ajax -> Asp.net [WebMethod]

Tags: asp.net, ajax, html, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

Problems uploading pictures from camera capture `<input type="file" capture="camera"` using JQM, Ajax, Asp.net [WebMethod].

I'll post some code below:

Script:

```
$('#uploadpicture').click(function() {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('photo', $('#filefromcam')[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "Butikk.aspx/UploadPicture",
            type: "POST",
            data: fd,
            processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
            contentType: false,   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
            success: function (data) {
                var result = data.d;
                console.log(data.d);
            },
            error: function (xhr, errorType, exception) { //Triggered if an error communicating with server  
                var errorMessage = exception || xhr.statusText; 
                alert("Feilmelding: " + errorMessage);
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<td>
<input type="file" id="filefromcam" capture="camera" accept="image/*" data-mini="true">
</td>
<td>
<a data-role="button" id="uploadpicture" data-mini="true">Last opp</a>
</td>
```

FORM TAG IN MASTER PAGE:

```
<form id="form" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

WEBMETHOD BACK-END

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UploadPicture(object fd)
{
   var test = "test";  // just to see if debug mode occurs for breakpoint.
}
```

The thing is, I always get POST localhost.../UploadPicture 200 OK 63MS
so it seems to be working, but I never get to the breakpoint I'm setting in the [WebMethod].

I have also tried XHR like this :

```
var file = input.files[0];
var form = new FormData();
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
form.append('image', file);
xhr.open('post', 'TestTest(dot)aspx/UploadPicture', true);  
xhr.send(form);
```

This should have been a solution too, but I just cannot get any other results no matter what i do or change.